# ¿Como puedo unir estas dos consultas SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Necesito unir esta consulta

```
SELECT CodContrato, FechaBaja, FechaFin
FROM Contrato
WHERE (
       (FechaBaja != FechaFin)
        OR (FechaBaja != **SEGUNDA CONSULTA**
AND (FechaBaja BETWEEN '20180101 00:00:00' AND '20181231 23:59:59')
```

con esta otra

```
SELECT CodContrato, FechaFinProrroga
FROM DatoAuxiliarContrato
WHERE FechaFinProrroga != '' AND (FechaFinProrroga BETWEEN '20180101 00:00:00' AND '20181231 23:59:59')
```

Ambas tablas tienen un campo en comun que es CodContrato

Estoy intentando con INNER JOIN pero no lo logro.
¿Podéis ayudarme?
Gracias de antemano

Comment: Para que te podamos contestar correctamente nos vendría muy bien que nos mostraras un esquema de las tablas o nos dijeras porque campo querrías unir

Comment: Como indica rencina no conocemos el esquema de las tablas que quieres unir, para poder hacer lo que deseas es necesario que tengan algún campo en común que permita enlazar los registros de ambas tablas pero con lo que indicas en el enunciado la información es insuficiente para poder ayudarte. Saludos!

Comment: si agregas datos del modelo te podemos ayudar un poco mas

Comment: @nerdcoder ambas consultas tienen CodContrato en comun

Comment: @JackNavaRow he editado, tienen un campo en comun ambas tablas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM Contrato
WHERE (
       (FechaBaja != FechaFin)
        OR (FechaBaja NOT IN (SELECT FechaFinProrroga
                                FROM DatoAuxiliarContrato
                               WHERE (FechaFinProrroga != '') AND (FechaFinProrroga BETWEEN '20180101 00:00:00' AND '20181231 23:59:59')
                              )  
            )         
      )
AND (FechaBaja BETWEEN '20180101 00:00:00' AND '20181231 23:59:59')
```

El operador `IN` dará como cierto si el valor se encuentra dentro de la siguiente lista (una subconsulta se trata como una lista).

Si quieres o sabes que solo habrá un valor en la subconsulta puedes hacer:

```
SELECT *
FROM Contrato
WHERE (
       (FechaBaja != FechaFin)
        OR (FechaBaja != (SELECT FechaFinProrroga
                                FROM DatoAuxiliarContrato
                               WHERE (FechaFinProrroga != '') AND (FechaFinProrroga BETWEEN '20180101 00:00:00' AND '20181231 23:59:59')
                               LIMIT 1 
                              )  
            )         
      )
AND (FechaBaja BETWEEN '20180101 00:00:00' AND '20181231 23:59:59')
```

Fijate en el `LIMIT 1`para asegurar que no se devolverá mas de un valor, lo cual daría error en la consulta.

Puedes encontrar más información sobre el uso de subconsultas en la documentación oficial https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/subqueries.html

(edito)

Según las últimas aclaraciones quedaría:

```
SELECT c.*
  FROM Contrato AS c
 WHERE (
       (c.FechaBaja != c.FechaFin)
        OR (c.FechaBaja NOT IN (SELECT aux.FechaFinProrroga
                                FROM DatoAuxiliarContrato AS aux
                               WHERE (aux.FechaFinProrroga != '') 
                                 AND (aux.FechaFinProrroga BETWEEN '20180101 00:00:00' AND '20181231 23:59:59') 
                                 AND (aux.CodContrato = c.DatoAuxiliarContrato)
                              )  
            )         
      )
 AND (c.FechaBaja BETWEEN '20180101 00:00:00' AND '20181231 23:59:59')
```

He añadido alias a las tablas, para aclarar un poco porque `FechaBaja` me genera muchas dudas.

Comment: y si explicas tu respuesta?

Comment: el LIMIT no me funciona ambos tienen CodContrato en comun

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar con union, aunque tienes que tener en cuenta que en la parte de SELECT las columnas tienen que ser las mismas en las dos partes de la union (o sustituyes el asterico de la primera por un solo campo o en la segunda añades a la fecha tantas columns como tenga la tabla contrato

```
SELECT *
FROM Contrato
WHERE 
(
    (FechaBaja != FechaFin)
    OR
    (FechaBaja != **SEGUNDA CONSULTA**)         
)
AND (FechaBaja BETWEEN '20180101 00:00:00' AND '20181231 23:59:59')
UNION
SELECT FechaFinProrroga
FROM DatoAuxiliarContrato
WHERE 
(FechaFinProrroga != '') AND (FechaBaja BETWEEN '20180101 00:00:00' AND '20181231 23:59:59')
```