# Unir 2 consultas mysql para obtener un resultado en comun

Tags: mysql

Tengo esta consulta:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM (

SELECT 
meses.id,
meses.nombre_mes,
count(asignacion.fecha_envio) AS cantidad,
SUM(hijos.valor) AS valor,
year(asignacion.fecha_envio) AS ano
FROM meses
left join asignacion ON meses.id = MONTH(asignacion.fecha_envio)
left join pedidos on pedidos.id = asignacion.id_pedido
left join hijos on hijos.id = pedidos.tratamiento 
WHERE asignacion.id_laboratorio = 4 AND asignacion.estado_envio = 'S' 
GROUP BY meses.id

UNION ALL

SELECT
meses.id, 
meses.nombre_mes, 
count(asignacion_etapas.fecha_envio) AS cantidad, 
SUM(hijos.valor) AS valor, 
year(asignacion_etapas.fecha_envio) AS ano
FROM meses
LEFT JOIN asignacion_etapas ON meses.id = 
MONTH(asignacion_etapas.fecha_envio)
left join hijos on hijos.id = asignacion_etapas.proc
WHERE asignacion_etapas.id_laboratorio = 4 AND asignacion_etapas.estado_envio = 'S' 

GROUP BY meses.id) as x
```

Lo que obtengo es lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y lo que deseo obtener o los resultados esperados, seria algo como esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea es sumar, contar y agrupar, tanto, cantidad, valor y mes es una sola fila. Desde ya muchas gracias a todos.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Como puedo unir estas dos consultas SQL?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/221192/como-puedo-unir-estas-dos-consultas-sql)

Comment: @RuslanLópez revise bien antes de publicar mi pregunta. El que los encabezados se escriban o suenen igual, no necesariamente tienen un fin duplicado, ya que ambas preguntan general resultados diferentes y buscan un objetivo diferente.

Comment: El problema es el mismo, unir el resultado de dos consultas, en dado caso explica en tu pregunta por qué no te sirve ninguna de las soluciones de la pregunta que estoy marcando como duplicada

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podés unir dos selects que devuelven la misma cantidad de columnas con los mismos tipos de datos usando `union`.

```
select t.id, t.nombre_mes, sum(t.cantidad) as cant_total, sum(t.valor) as valor_total, t.ano
from(
    SELECT
    meses.id,
    meses.nombre_mes,
    count(asignacion.fecha_envio) AS cantidad,
    SUM(hijos.valor) AS valor,
    year(asignacion.fecha_envio) AS ano
    FROM meses
    left join asignacion ON meses.id = MONTH(asignacion.fecha_envio)
    left join pedidos on pedidos.id = asignacion.id_pedido
    left join hijos on hijos.id = pedidos.tratamiento 
    WHERE asignacion.id_laboratorio = 4 AND asignacion.estado_envio = 'S'  
    GROUP BY meses.id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
    meses.id, 
    meses.nombre_mes, 
    count(asignacion_etapas.fecha_envio) AS cantidad, 
    SUM(hijos.valor) AS valor, 
    year(asignacion_etapas.fecha_envio) AS ano
    FROM meses
    LEFT JOIN asignacion_etapas ON meses.id = MONTH(asignacion_etapas.fecha_envio)
    left join hijos on hijos.id = asignacion_etapas.proc
    WHERE asignacion_etapas.id_laboratorio = 4 AND asignacion_etapas.estado_envio = 'S' 
    GROUP BY meses.id
) as t
group by t.id, t.nombre_mes, t.ano
```

Comment: muchas gracias por responder. Si bien tu respuesta arroja lo que busco, necesito tb que se sume o agrupe todo por el mes correspondiente. De manera que pueda queda en diciembre por ej, la suma de las cantidades y valores en un solo registro correspondiente a eses mes. Gracias por tu ayuda. Saludos

Comment: Entonces debes usar [subconsultas](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/subqueries.html), el `UNION` que indica @Juan  seria la subconsulta y la principal tendria el `SUM(cantidad), SUM(valor)` (o columnas que necesites) agrupado por la columna mes.

Comment: Agrega a la pregunta un ejemplo de la salida esperada de los dos queries consolidados, si puede ser donde tengas el mismo registro en ambos queries, dado que el comentario puede interpretarse de varias formas. Por ejemplo los agregados (sumas count) son parte de cada query individual o deben ser consolidados en conjunto una vez unidos los dos queries base?

Comment: @Juan edite mi respuesta y agregue una imagen de los resultados que necesito. La idea es agrupar en una sola fila (id y nombre_mes) las cantidades y los valores correspondientes a cada mes, espero puedas ayudarme, de antemano, muchas gracias.

Comment: Modifique el query como comentó @Flyn

Comment: era lo que necesitaba, muchisimas gracias a ambos por su tiempo y ayuda. saludos.